# There are 9 blocks whats the length and width of one block. the pic has the rest of the info for the question

Tags: contest-math

[The rest of the questions information is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h16Xp.png)
I'm really confused. Please help me with this question.

Comment: Please give some context and write the problem directly in the question.

Comment: @jojobo I certainly agree with the need for context, although that is somewhat provided by the *contest-math* tag; that is, the OP is supposed to show work.  I also agree that it is better to imbed the graphic **in** the query, rather than having to *switch back and forth* between the graphic and the query.  **However**, other than these considerations, I think that this is one of those unusual situations, where the elegance of presenting a problem via a graphic takes priority over trying to reduce the essential elements of the graphic into mathematical constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, length=x and width=y.

Thus, from the figure
$$9xy=1620$$
$$xy=180$$

Also, from the 2nd figure,
$$4x=5y$$
$$x=\frac{5y}{4}$$
Put it in the 1st equation:
$$\frac{5y^2}{4}=180$$
$$y^2=144$$
$$y=12$$
Thus,
$$x=\frac{5y}{4}=15$$

Thus dimensions of a single block are $15*12$